# How make Python acess another database

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I have a problem with the database. I need to create a button that can change the database and access another. For example, I'm with the database: data.db. Clicking "change" changes the targeting, and it connects to data2.db. I have no idea how to do a function that changes access to another database. I am grateful to anyone who can help me.

```
class griffo:
db_name = 'database.db'

 def __init__(self, window):


        self.wind = window

        self.wind.title('GRIFFO HISTORYPEDIA')

        #This is the code to insert a icon on the main WINDOW

        icon = PhotoImage(file='griffoicone.png') 
        self.wind.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.wind._w, icon)

        self.wind.configure(background='gray15')

        framename = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = '', foreground="azure")
        framename.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
        framename.configure(background='gray15')

def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS griffo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , name TEXT, geografia TEXT, economico TEXT, social TEXT, tecnologico TEXT, cultural TEXT, colaborador TEXT)")
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result
```

Comment: The only place where your code knows about the database name is in this line:  `with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:`. So, if the two databases have identical structures, all you need to do is get your button to change the value of `griffo.db_name`.

Comment: Yes, I already thought of that. but I am beginner I do not know which function can change the value. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates the simple code that is required:

```
>>> griffo.db_name
'database.db'
>>> griffo.db_name = 'database2.db'
>>> griffo.db_name
'database2.db'
```

So, attach `griffo.db_name = 'database2.db'` to your button.

If your button is `change` then

```
change = tk.Button(frame,
               text="Change",
               command=on_change)

def on_change():
    griffo.db_name = 'database2.db'
```

Comment: Hello, it looks like I did not understand this code. Could you make a functional example? I do not understand what these characters means: >>> and I do not know what kind of function I would be referring to: >>> griffo.db_name
'database.db'.

Comment: To illustrate I simply typed the code in at the Python prompt. The Python prompt is `>>>` and if you run the Python interpreter it will invite you to type Python that way. They are not part of the code and you don't put them in your program. I am guessing your GUI framework is `tkinter` (though you didn't actually say that) and I've added an elementary event handler to the answer.